# SherlockListFragment cachecolorhint

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I used the FragmentTabsPager example to implement view pager on my application. I am using a SherlockListFragment and and asynctask to get data and set the adapter.The list appears on the fragment,but the problem is that I cannot set the list android:cachecolorhint, and  it is white (I suppose it is because of the theme). how can I change this?

Thank you,

Comment: Please post your xml where you try to set cachecolorhint. Maybe try `cachecolorhint` instead of `android:cachecolorhint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorted, just used  getListView().setCacheColorHint(0); in my onactivitycreated method